# django-mongodb-engine can't update an object

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am writing a Django-based back end using django-mongodb-engine for an android app and I'm trying to get data from a PUT request to update a record in my database.  I'm getting a username and filtering the database for the user object with that name (successfully), but the save function doesn't seem to be saving the changes.  I can tell the changes aren't being saved because when I go onto mLab's online database management tool the changes aren't there.

Here's the code:

```
existing_user = User.objects.filter(userName = user_name)
        if existing_user == None:
            response_string += "<error>User not identified: </error>"

        elif (existing_user[0].password != user_pwd):
            response_string += "<error>Password error.</error>"

        #if we have a validated user, then manipulate user data
        else:
            existing_user[0].star_list.append(new_star)
            existing_user[0].save()
```

I'm not getting any error messages, but the data remains the same.  The star_list remains empty after the above.  In fact, as a test I even tried replacing the else clause above with:

```
else: 
    existing_user[0].userName = "Barney"
    existing_user[0].save()
```

And following this call, the existing_user[0].userName is still it's original value ("Fred", rather than "Barney")!

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to this question.  I'm not sure why it wasn't working as posted, but there were problems trying to access the object through the list... in other words the following didn't work:

```
existing_user[0].userName = "Barney"
existing_user[0].save()
```

But this did:

```
found_user = existing_user[0]
found_user.userName = "Barney"
found_user.save()
```

Based on my understanding of Python lists, either one should be the same... but maybe some python genius out there can explain why they aren't?